# How to iterate files in directory with for loop in Bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to iterate all files in a directory with for loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

myname="bandit24"

cd /var/spool/$myname
echo "Executing and deleting all scripts in /var/spool/$myname:"

for file in /var/spool/bandit24/*; #  <----- here
do
    if [ "$file" != "." -a "$file" != ".." ];
    then
        echo "Handling $file"
        owner="$(stat --format "%U" ./$file)"
        if [ "${owner}" = "bandit24" ]; then
            timeout -s 9 60 ./$file
        fi
        rm -f ./$file
    fi
done
```

But as a result I get the following:

```
Executing and deleting all scripts in /var/spool/bandit24:
Handling /var/spool/bandit24/*
stat: cannot stat './/var/spool/bandit24/*': No such file or directory
```

The program is not trying to iterate files in `/var/spool/bandit24/` directory, but it tries to iterate `/var/spool/bandit24/*` file itself. But I want to iterate files in `/var/spool/bandit24/` directory. How to do it?

***Additional question***

What does `cd /var/spool/$myname` mean (5 line)? As I understand, it is used for specifying the directory we are going to work in, am I right?

Comment: The output is not from the script that you posted.  Please make that consistent. Also, if you put `do` on the new line, there is no need to put a `;` at the end of the line with `for`. As for your additional question: Yes.

Comment: What you see is the consequence of `/var/spool/bandit24` being empty. In this case `/var/spool/bandit24/*` expands as itself. If you prefer that it expands as null you can enable the `nullglob` bash option before your for loop: `shopt -s nullglob`.

Comment: As variable `myname` is assigned `bandit24`, `cd /var/spool/$myname` is the same as `cd /var/spool/bandit24`. You should probably rewrite it as `cd /var/spool/"$myname" || exit 1`. Double quotes just in case the `myname` value contains spaces (it is not the case now but who knows what you will be doing next). And `|| exit 1` to abort your script if the directory does not exist and the `cd` command fails. This should avoid unwanted behaviors like executing and deleting all scripts in the current directory...

Comment: @RenaudPacalet The reason why I said that this is not the output of the script are twofold: the for-loop does not produce the `stat`. The (unspecified) command in the for-loop does that. If you put `rm -f "$file"` there, it won't produce the error message. Second, the `stat` cannot find `.//var.spool/bandit24/*`. The `./` makes it unlikely that this comes from this script.

Comment: @LjmDullaart I agree, but I assume that the `.//var/` is a typo.

Comment: @LjmDullaart I've edited my question and added the body of the for loop.

Comment: @RodionIskhakov Apart the issues I explained already you have another: with `for file in /var/spool/bandit24/*`, if the directory is not empty, variable `file` will take values like `/var/spool/bandit24/foobar`, not just `foobar`. So you cannot use it with `./$file`. Solution: as you `cd` in the `/var/spool/bandit24` directory, simply write `for file in *`.

Comment: @RodionIskhakov If you follow my suggestion `if [ "$file" != "." -a "$file" != ".." ]` becomes useless: these two names don't match `/var/spool/bandit24/*`. Still, double quote all references to `$file` (`stat --format "%U" ./"$file"`, `timeout -s 9 60 ./"$file"`, `rm -f ./"$file"`). If you don't you take real risks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for-loop is basically sound. However, if the directory is empty, the loop will be executed once, with the variable `file` containing the literal text `/var/spool/bandit24/*`.

The `stat` message is not from the `for`-loop, but from one of the commands in the loop.

The correct way would be to test if the directory is empty before you continue. You could put something like

```
if [ $(find . -type f | wc -l) -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "Nothing to do"
    exit 0
fi
```

right after the `cd`.

Some other comments on your script.

- If you do a `cd` in the script, you don't need to specify the full path anymore.
- Your quoting is not really consistent. That may not be a problem if your file names never contain spaces or strange characters, but I would, for example `timeout -s 9 60 "./$file"` and `rm -f "./file"`
- `/var/spool/bandit/*` will never contain `.` or `..`, so that test is useless.
- You could also replace the test with `if [ -f "$file" ] ; then`

Comment: Or use `shopt -s nullglob`

Answer (score 3):

```sh
for f in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f); do
    echo "current file is $f"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

i've a bash script in my [Github repo](https://github.com/marciovsrocha/todolist/blob/master/teste.sh) who iterates over all files in specified directory. You can specify the deepth of search, it's something like this.

```
mapfile files <<< "$(find "$f" -maxdepth "$d" ! -type d)"
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    file="$(tr -d '\n' <<< "$file")"
    # implement your logic here
done
```

- `$files` is an array with file names
- `$f` contains the directory
- `$d` is the depth of search, default is 1 (only for specified folder)
- `$file` contains the file name as `$path_to_file/$filename`

Comment: Would be much better with `mapfile -d '' files < <(find "$f" -maxdepth "$d" ! -type d -print0)"` reading a null-delimited results stream. Also combining command expansion and here-string is not necessary. `file="$(tr -d '\n' <<< "$file")"` would have been avoided with `mapfile -t`. It is not needed either with mapping null-delimited entries. (See `help mapfile` in a bash shell)

Answer (score 0):

- What you see is the consequence of `/var/spool/bandit24` being empty. In this case `/var/spool/bandit24/*` expands as itself. If you prefer that it expands as null you can enable the `nullglob` bash option before your for loop: `shopt -s nullglob`.
- As variable `myname` is assigned `bandit24`, `cd /var/spool/$myname` is the same as `cd /var/spool/bandit24`. You should probably rewrite it as `cd /var/spool/"$myname" || exit 1`. Double quotes just in case the `myname` value contains spaces (it is not the case now but who knows what you will be doing next). And `|| exit 1` to abort your script if the directory does not exist and the `cd` command fails. This should avoid unwanted behaviors like executing and deleting all scripts in the current directory instead of the non-existing one...
- with `for file in /var/spool/bandit24/*`, if the directory is not empty, variable `file` will take values like `/var/spool/bandit24/foobar`, not just `foobar`. So you cannot use it with `./$file`. Solution: as you `cd` in the `/var/spool/bandit24` directory, simply write `for file in *`.
- You should really double quote all references to `$file` (`stat --format "%U" "$file"`, `timeout -s 9 60 ./"$file"`, `rm -f "$file"`). If you don't you take real risks.

Try the following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

myname="bandit24"

cd /var/spool/"$myname" || exit 1
echo "Executing and deleting all scripts in /var/spool/$myname:"

shopt -s nullglob
for file in *; do
    echo "Handling $file"
    owner=$(stat --format "%U" "$file")
    if [ "$owner" = "$myname" ]; then
        timeout -s 9 60 ./"$file"
    fi
    rm -f "$file"
done
```